# SystemD per unit LogRateLimitIntervalSec not working?

Tags: systemd, centos8

SystemD journal limits logged messages according to `RateLimitIntervalSec` and `RateLimitBurst` global configuration options. There is a possibility to change those values per specific unit/service using `LogRateLimitIntervalSec` and `LogRateLimitBurst` directives. Unfortunately I can't make these per-service options work. I hope that you will help me find what I'm doing wrong or confirm that there is something wrong with systemd.

My environment:

```
# uname -srvmpio
Linux 4.18.0-193.14.2.el8_2.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Jul 26 03:54:29 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 8.2.2004 (Core)

# systemctl --version
systemd 239
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=legacy

# rsyslogd -v
rsyslogd  8.1911.0-3.el8 (aka 2019.11)
```

Make sure global journald limits are left as default in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`:

```
[Journal]
#RateLimitIntervalSec=30s
#RateLimitBurst=10000
```

and restart if any change was necessary

```
systemctl restart systemd-journald
```

Prepare the test script `/root/test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..1000000}
do
   echo "Hello world $i"
done
```

Prepare the test service unit `/root/test.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Test limit service

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/root
ExecStart=/root/test.sh
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=test
LogRateLimitIntervalSec=0
LogRateLimitBurst=0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Make sure rsyslog rate limit is off by changing `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
module(load="imjournal"
       StateFile="imjournal.state"
       Ratelimit.Interval="0")
```

Configure test service log file location by creating `/etc/rsyslog.d/test.conf`:

```
if ($programname == 'test') then {
    action(
        type="omfile"
        File="/root/test.log"
    )
    stop
}
```

Restart rsyslog:

```
systemctl restart rsyslog
```

Install the test service:

```
# systemctl enable /root/test.service
```

Verify test service rate limit settings (`LogRateLimitIntervalSec` is internally stored as `LogRateLimitIntervalUSec`):

```
# systemctl show --property LogRateLimitIntervalUSec test.service --no-pager
LogRateLimitIntervalUSec=0

# systemctl show --property LogRateLimitBurst test.service --no-pager
LogRateLimitBurst=0
```

Start the service:

```
systemctl start test.service
```

My result:

- /root/test.log stops at `Hello world 12500`
- `journalctl -u test.service --no-pager` stops at `Hello world 12500`
- /var/log/messages reports (sometimes this message is not logged)

```
systemd-journald[304398]: Suppressed 982500 messages from test.service
```

I've also confirmed that changing the global journald settings to (and restarting systemd-journald):

```
[Journal]
RateLimitIntervalSec=0
RateLimitBurst=0
```

results in no rate limiting as expected.

I'm clueless at this point. Even tried to analyze the systemd source code but it's over my head.
If anyone would at least recreate my steps and report the results that would be helpful in reporting this on systemd Github issue tracker.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RateLimitIntervalSec=, RateLimitBurst=` section in `man journald.conf` says:

> To turn off any kind of rate limiting, set either value to 0.

However you cannot find this in the `LogRateLimitIntervalSec=, LogRateLimitBurst=` section in `man systemd.exec`. With your `test.service` you can easy verify that setting this to something other than `0` does work as expected.

Comment: Thank you. I'll ask on Github if it was desired to work like that.

Comment: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/22034

Comment: Great, thank you! It seems this is rather complicated.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `RateLimitIntervalSec` is `RateLimitInterval` on CentOS 7.